# How to customize Android 10 (Samsung A10) Chrome Share menu (from mobile Chrome0?

Tags: android, google-chrome

I used to be able to override a flag in Chrome to hide the default share screen, thus giving direct/one-tap access to all the apps on my phone, but the option appears to be done now with Android 10.

I guess it could be sharing from any app on my phone, not just Chrome.

Any other way to do this?

Thanks.